# How can I wrap a block in jinja2

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I basically want to do something like this in my base template:

```
{% if the block 'headline' is not empty %}
<div class="something"><h1>{% block headline %}{% end block %}</h1></div>
{% endif %}
```

In jinja2 it appears blocks are not variables and you can't get at their contents or test their values, or anything else but output them.

This seems like it would be a no-brainer to allow this, but I can't figure out a way.  Do I have to use macros instead of blocks?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able check the contents of a block using the `self.blockname` syntax.

```
{% if self.headline() is not empty %}
{# Write out Headline HTML wrapper here #}
{% endif %}
```

To quote from [the documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#child-template):

> If you want to print a block multiple times you can however use the special self variable and call the block with that name:

```
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
<h1>{{ self.title() }}</h1>
{% block body %}{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I have used this to add a pipe into a page title if a content_title has been supplied: `<title>{% block content_title %}{% endblock %}{% if self.content_title() %} | {% endif %}{{ SITENAME }}</title>`. Hopefully this makes it more clear for using this in an if statement.

Comment: @Treffynnon This was exactly what I was googling for to figure out how to do.  Thanks!